# What should be used to represent creature tokens when the printed token card isn't available?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Many spells or abilities cause one or more creatures to join the battlefield (i.e. 1/1 white Soldier creature tokens, 3/3 green Beast creature tokens, etc.). These token cards are not included with the cards that require them.

What do MtG players use instead to represent token creatures?

A quick search shows you can buy packs of such cards, but I'm wondering what convenient ways exist to represent these tokens without actually having to buy more cards?

Comment: VTC too broad -- I feel that this is essentially a list question, as the rules allow for almost anything, so long as the board state is clear to all players

Comment: A reminder to answerers that this question is asking for real play advice, an explanation of how it tends to be handled, and an overall picture of the situation in MTG. This is not an invitation to share the various unique ways _you personally_ do it - this is not a discussion forum nor a survey, and answering that way is a [Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) answer, or the kind that [we try to avoid](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Avoid filling the question up with these.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a creature token represent a different creature token?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/10782/can-a-creature-token-represent-a-different-creature-token)

Comment: @Hackworth Regarding duplication, I searched B&CG for 10 minutes before posting this question and was not able to find the question you referenced. I also searched the internet for a couple minutes. While that question's answer pretty much answers my question, the title and question is not what I was asking and is therefore pretty hard to find for someone asking my more general question - which seems to me a natural question to ask for someone new to this game (such as myself).

Comment: @JoeGolton You are correct to judge duplication by question, and not by answers. This is not a duplicate. My only small nitpick with your question is that I'd prefer if you asked "What *can* I use [...]" instead of "What *should* I use [...]".

Comment: The only difference I see between the questions is the wording: this question is an open question, asking **what** can be used to sub for missing token cards, while the question I linked to asked the question in a closed-ended manner, **whether or not** a different token card can sub for the actual token card. If the most relevant difference between two questions is semantic and both questions can be given the same answer, I believe that those questions are identical.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can cover what is legal and what is common, and you can hopefully determine what is "convenient". The MTG Tournament Rules dictate that you clearly represent your board state. This means:

- You must be able to represent the tapped state of your token
- You must be able to differentiate types of tokens
- Tokens must not be in the same sleeves as the deck you are playing

  - This is under Section 3.8 of the [Tournament Policy](http://rules.wizards.com/rulebook.aspx?game=Magic&category=Tournament%20Policy)

    > [...] Sleeves or card backs that appear similar to any player’s sleeves or card backs may not be used as markers. [...]
  - Notably, if you are playing without sleeves, you may not use an unsleeved Magic card as a token

I see no reason to ignore these rules for casual play. They aren't very limiting.

The most common legal method of representing a token, for those lacking the actual token card, is a plain face down card. *Any* card. If you control multiple types of tokens, it must be clear to both players which cards represent which tokens.

Some players use dice to represent tokens. Depending on what kind of dice you use, it can be difficult or impossible to tell whether a particular token is tapped or untapped. It's also unclear whether a "2" means "two tokens" or "one 2/2 token". You can overcome this by using dice that don't have rotational symmetry and by communicating clearly. I still advise against it because there are easier, clearer options (my opinion).

Representing a large number of tokens individually may not be feasible. In these cases, you can group tokens that have the same status using a single card with a numeric counter placed on top. Every token in the group must be identical. If some are tapped, or if some have summoning sickness, represent them as a separate group.

Comment: Those rules *can* be limiting. The third one, especially, can be a huge pain if you can generate a ton of tokens. Especially in a casual game, situations could come up where a player generates an unwieldy number of tokens (such as with Rhys the Redeemed), and having a separate object for each would be impossible. I also think the first one can be ignored for objects that aren't affected by tapping (such as enchantments), but that's a rare case.

Comment: @murgtroid99 I did a little bit of research and it looks like I just made number 3 up because a local judge requires players to represent their tokens individually. It's been removed, and number 1 reworded to cover it more precisely and with a [not so authoritative] reference.

Comment: I would be curious to see a more explicit statement of that from a judge. _Technically_, the rules excerpt you've quoted says that sleeves cannot be used as markers, but it doesn't say that sleeved cardboard can't be used as markers, assuming whatever is in the sleeve suitably identifies the type of token (e.g. one of the token inserts distributed in boosters).

Comment: When you are talking about unsleeved cards, is it only considered a card if it has the magic backing and that it isn't really considered a card if it has an ad on the back?

Comment: @LukeDrew Exactly. Advertisement cards cannot match any player's sleeve (or lack of), and so they are always safe to use.

Comment: I think it might be useful to note in this answer that an easy way to use a small amount of tokens to represent more than two (i.e. if you used Elspeth, Sun's Champion's plus one to create 3 soldiers) would be to put two dice on it, one to represent tapped # of soldiers and one to represent untapped. I'm not sure how to word that in a good enough way to match the rest of the already solid answer, just thought I'd mention it as a possibility.

Comment: @JoeyWunderlich Yes, that sort of situation occurs often, so it would be useful to include in the answer. Added.

Comment: Dice with solid numbers instead of dots can work, as they can tap. Just get colored dice to keep track of creature color, and write down anything that has to do with them having keywords (like flying) if you cant remember.

Comment: @ShadowZ. I hadn't thought about that when I wrote "Dice cannot tap." I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 6):

[image: PoTo Life Counter and Creature token]Most counters and methods use dice or cards to represent that there is a token, or that it has counters on it. But there is only one product I've found that displays power/toughness and can double as a tappable creature token on its own.  It's from Jace's Toy Chest. Only place i've found them is on Etsy and ebay.

Comment: A link or more precise name of this item might be helpful for people who are looking for it.

Answer (score 5):

When ever I play magic with my brother or friends, we use sticky notes.
You can write any abilities they might have just as long as you bring a pen. I use smaller sticky notes as ++ tokens too.

This method is occasionally used for feature matches (i.e., matches that get video coverage) at large tournaments, but only when a better alternative is not available. For example, there is no official marker for which mode is chosen for [Outpost Siege](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=outpost+siege) (Dragons or Khans), so a sticky is used instead.

Answer (score 3):

My friends and I use cards that aren't in the current game, face-down. We put coins (1, 2 or 5 cents) on them depending on the power/toughness of the creature tokens (since most of the time, they have equal power and toughness).

Comment: Alternative to coins: dice (1 through 6), which is handy if they go up (or down) in value through enchantments or other means.

Comment: There are good reasons to separate base power/toughness, P/T from continuous effects, and P/T from counters. If you merge them all together it can become difficult to track what the original base was.

Comment: @Joe Golton, That's a bad idea for numerous reasons. Just leave it at the base P/T like on cards.

Comment: @JoeGolton If you do use dice, it's probably best to use a distinct color/type of dice for the base power/toughness, so that if you add counters (and also represent them with dice) you can keep them straight.

Answer (score 3):

Our group uses index cards, which is pretty handy because you can just write the static stats (color, creature type, BASE P/T, etc) on the card. D6 on top of the card is usually enough for counters, and d10/20 to count a group of identical tokens if things start getting... silly...

Answer (score 1):

I put all my ad cards in white, blue, green, red, or black sleeves and put those face down with a dice on them.

Comment: Using the colors of the sleeves to represent the color of the token wouldn't work very well for multicolored tokens, such as a [Elemental](http://shop.tcgplayer.com/magic/return-to-ravnica/elemental-token-(green-white)) (green-white), or colorless tokens, such as [Thopter](http://shop.tcgplayer.com/magic/shards-of-alara/thopter-token).

Answer (score 0):

Mini Dice and flipped cards. My friends typically up just use dice. If you want you can easily get a lot of token cards since almost all of them are super cheap.

Answer (score 0):

As far as dice go, use two dice for a 2/2 token. When they are horizontal, the token is untapped. Twist them both so they are vertical, and it's tapped.

Answer (score 0):

I just use a face-down card and put a piece of paper on it with its stats

Comment: Welcome to the site Red Dawn! Consider taking the [tour](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information on how to write good answers or questions.

Answer (score -3):

Yugioh cards find a creature card that represents the token it is supposed to be. You can buy one in playsets of 3 for 2$.

Comment: Given that this question is about Magic the Gathering this answer isn't particularly helpful here.

Comment: The suggestion sounds like: get a random yugioh card that looks like the thing and use that for the token, *but* I'm downvoting because it doesn't very well address the question itself. We are *probably* not going to benefit from building up a big list of all the token options, because we don't handle list questions well.